# How to return array with custom value on php function?

Tags: php, function

I have a function called function people(). This function normally will return an array as shown below:

```
 [ 
   "name"=>"jhon",
   "age"=>23,
   "address"=>"Denpasar",
   "phone"=>01293127,
   "email"=>jhondo@gmail.com,
   "hobby"=>"football"
]
```

Now I want to pass same payload for example :

```
people('name,age')
```

and what I expected as result is

```
  [
   "name"=>"jhon",
   "age"=>23,
  ]
```

How can I do that? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Pass in an array of keys younwant to retrieve, and return only those keys that match, and if no array is passed in, return everything.

Comment: hi bro thanks for your replay ,but sorry i just beginner and i din't get what exactly what you mean . can you show some example please

Comment: i got the answer

Comment: ```  <?php function people($param = null)
{


    $people = [
        "name" => "leo",
        "age" => 134,
        "hobby" => "nap"
    ];

    if ($param === null) {
        return $people;
    }

    $param = explodeString($param);
    $myArray = [];
    foreach ($param as $param) {
        $myArray[$param] = $people[$param];
    }
    return $myArray;
}

function explodeString($str)
{
    return explode(",", $str);
}


print_r(people('name,age')); ?>```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the array of keys you want to get as a optional param of the function:

```php
function people($return_keys = NULL) {
    $result = [...]; // Your current logic
    if (is_array($return_keys)) {
        return array_intersect_key($result, array_flip($return_keys)); 
    }
    return $result; // If no array is passed, return all keys
}
```